# search:search options migration from MarkLogic 7 to version 8

Tags: search, namespaces, marklogic, migrate

I'm trying to migrate a search app written in XQuery from MarkLogic 7 to version 8 and I've hit this Known Incompatibility issue about the constraint namespace in the options. I've tried to add the default json/basic namespace and then a custom namespace, didn't work. When I run the below code in Query Console webpage looses connection and reloads after a few seconds. I've even recreated an element range index, after I installed ML 8 all my DBs were recognized, I've reindexed the target DB. Don't know what else could be wrong. Any guidance would be highly appreciated, thanks!

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

declare variable $options := 
<search:options xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search:search-option>unfiltered</search:search-option>
  <search:page-length>30</search:page-length>
  <search:term apply="term">
    <search:empty apply="all-results"/>
    <search:term-option>punctuation-insensitive</search:term-option>
    <search:term-option>stemmed</search:term-option>
  </search:term>
  <search:grammar>
    <search:quotation>"</search:quotation>
    <search:implicit>
      <cts:and-query strength="20" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"/>
    </search:implicit>
    <search:starter strength="30" apply="grouping" delimiter=")">(</search:starter>
    <search:starter strength="40" apply="prefix" element="cts:not-query">-</search:starter>
    <search:joiner strength="10" apply="infix" element="cts:or-query" tokenize="word">OR</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="20" apply="infix" element="cts:and-query" tokenize="word">AND</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="30" apply="infix" element="cts:near-query" tokenize="word">NEAR</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="30" apply="near2" consume="2" element="cts:near-query">NEAR/</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint">:</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LT" tokenize="word">LT</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="LE" tokenize="word">LE</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GT" tokenize="word">GT</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="GE" tokenize="word">GE</search:joiner>
    <search:joiner strength="50" apply="constraint" compare="NE" tokenize="word">NE</search:joiner>
  </search:grammar>
  <search:additional-query>
    <cts:not-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
      <cts:or-query>
    <cts:collection-query>
      <cts:uri>ontology</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>Gemeentes</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>Wijken</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>Buurten</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>Wijk_Hierarchy</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>Buurt_Hierarchy</cts:uri>
      <cts:uri>Kerncijfers_wijken_en_buurten_2014</cts:uri>
    </cts:collection-query>
    <cts:element-query>
      <cts:element xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">sem:triples</cts:element>
      <cts:or-query/>
    </cts:element-query>
      </cts:or-query>
    </cts:not-query>
  </search:additional-query>
  <search:debug>false</search:debug>
  <search:extract-metadata>
    <search:qname elem-name="Vhe"/>
    <search:qname elem-name="OpnameType"/>
    <search:qname elem-name="Plaats"/>
    <search:qname elem-name="Straat"/>
      <search:constraint-value ref="Plaats"/>
    <search:constraint-value ref="Straat"/>
    <search:constraint-value ref="Keuken_Beoordeling"/>
      <search:constraint-value ref="Badkamer_Beoordeling"/>
    <search:constraint-value ref="location"/>
  </search:extract-metadata>

  <search:transform-results apply="snippet"/>

  <search:constraint name="location">
    <search:geo-elem-pair>
      <search:parent name="location"/>
      <search:lat name="lat"/>
      <search:lon name="lng"/>
      <search:geo-option>units=miles</search:geo-option>
      <search:geo-option>coordinate-system=wgs84</search:geo-option>
      <search:heatmap n="50.0006240" s="52.384274889550028" w="5.1864790" e="6.8864790" latdivs="14" londivs="19"/>
    </search:geo-elem-pair>
  </search:constraint>

  <search:constraint name="Plaats">
    <search:range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <search:element name="Plaats"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:constraint name="Straat">
    <search:range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <search:element name="Straat"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:constraint name="Complex">
    <search:range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <search:element name="Complex"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:constraint name="Keuken_Beoordeling">
    <search:range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <search:element name="Keuken_Beoordeling"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:constraint name="Badkamer_Beoordeling">
    <search:range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <search:element name="Badkamer_Beoordeling"/>
    </search:range>
  </search:constraint>
  <search:return-metrics>true</search:return-metrics>
  <search:return-qtext>true</search:return-qtext>
  <search:return-query>false</search:return-query>
  <search:return-results>true</search:return-results>
  <search:return-similar>false</search:return-similar>
  <search:sort-order direction="descending">
  <search:score/>
  <search:annotation>Relevancy (Desc)</search:annotation>
</search:sort-order>
</search:options>;

 search:search("wieer", $options, xs:unsignedLong(1), 150)
```

Comment: Is MarkLogic restarting? Are there any relevant errors in `ErrorLog.txt`?

Comment: Were the elements such as Straat converted from JSON keys using json:transform() with the basic configuration?  If so, the search:element should have an ns attribute of "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic" (or the JSON should be reingested as native JSON and the options should use search:json-property instead).

Comment: Yes, I get the following error and server restarts.

Comment: Thread: ACCESS_VIOLATION
#  1 0x0000000140290185 in xdmp::OnDiskFewGeoRangesLazyItemIterator::next() (ondiskrangeindexes.cpp:29299)

Comment: Will contact support for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated the DB from scratch, copied data with the latest mlcp from the ML 7 DB to the newly created ML 8 DB. Recreated the indexes, but the crash was still happening. Then, I filtered out from the search options which section caused the crash. It is this one:

```
  <search:constraint name="location">
    <search:geo-elem-pair>
      <search:parent name="location"/>
      <search:lat name="lat"/>
      <search:lon name="lng"/>
      <search:geo-option>units=miles</search:geo-option>
      <search:geo-option>coordinate-system=wgs84</search:geo-option>
      <search:heatmap n="50.0006240" s="52.384274889550028" w="5.1864790" e="6.8864790" latdivs="14" londivs="19"/>
    </search:geo-elem-pair>
  </search:constraint>
```

Once I removed this, was not really using it in the search results, there were no more issues.

Comment: Narrowed it even further. The following search option line causes the crash continuously:  <!--search:heatmap n="50.0006240" s="52.384274889550028" w="5.1864790" e="6.8864790" latdivs="14" londivs="19"/-->

Answer (score 1):

As Joe points out, the server may be crashing and automatically restarting. Check `ErrorLog.txt` to verify that. Make sure you have the [very latest release](http://developer.marklogic.com/download): right now it's 8.0-1.1.

The test case does **not** crash on my laptop with 8.0-1.1 and the necessary index settings. However I don't have any matching documents so it doesn't do very much. That may mean that the crash, if that's what's happening, requires some of your content too. You could try an empty database to verify that, then try to establish whether or not the problem is linked to a specific set of documents.

If the problem persists, [contact support](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/copyright/support) to report it.

Comment: Indeed I've installed version 8.0-1.1

Comment: The database was also used in ML 7 and after I've installed ML 8 it automatically recognized all my previous DBs, security settings and DB settings, including the indexes. I just reindexed the DB. All my documents are XML as they were in ML7. I'll check the logs and do some more tests. Thanks for your help!